# Symbolic definition for $i$?

Tags: complex-analysis, systems-of-equations, quaternions, parity

Please help!

I am trying to find a definition for $i$ that doesn't work for $-i$.

let $j$ be either $i$ or $-i$.

- saying $j^2=-1$ doesn't help since $(i)^2=-1$ and $(-i)^2 = -1$
- saying $j=\sqrt{-1}$ doesn't halp since $(-1)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is multivalued $i$ and $-i$
- saying $j=e^{i\pi/2}$ doesnt help since $e^{i\pi/2}=i$ but $e^{(-i)\pi/2}=-i$ too (yeah I know I said j=$e^{i\pi/2}$ and not $j=e^{j\pi/2}$ I did that to hopefully make it more intuitive)
- saying $j=ln(i)/(\pi/2)$ doesn't work since $i=ln(i)/(\pi/2)$ and $-i=ln(-i)/(pi/2)$ (check with a phase plotter, ln is multivalued but includes i and -i in their respective functions shown above http://davidbau.com/conformal/#log(z)%2F(pi%2F2)-z)
- saying $Im(j) > 0$ doesn't work because $Im(z)=Re(z/i)$ and $Re(i/i)>0$ but $Re((-i)/(-i))>0$

Is this parity some sort of law? And yet $i\neq-i$ since $i=(-1)\cdot(-i)$. Unless...

Post Scriptum: Irionically, it is very easy to symbolically represent $1$ vs $-1$ even though $(1)^2=1$ and $(-1)^2=1$, we can just say $x$ such that $x=x^2$

EDIT: can quaternions help? Is $i$ a set of 2 numbers? Are they always equal?

Comment: The two solutions to $i^2=-1$ are not equal: if you add one to the other you get $0$ rather than twice one of them.  But they do have the same properties as each other, as Favst points out in an answer.  Quaternions would not help and face a similar issue in identification.

Comment: Algebraically, $\pm i$ are indistinguishable.

Comment: Does this count? $\ln(-1)=i\pi$, not $-i\pi$? This is a function that behaves differently for $i$ and $-i$ (by convention).

Comment: @runway44 a question remains, whether they are distinguishable analytically (see my post).

Comment: @Anixx : This convention requires that you have previously fixed the complex unit. So it would be a circular definition.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I am not sure about this (but not convinced either way). I think we can define $i$ analytically as $i=-\frac1\pi\int_{-1}^1 \frac1x dx$. That is, if we integrate a function with simple pole, and left limit is negative infinite, we get $-i$ up to positive coefficient. In what sense this is different from analytic definition of $\varepsilon$ in my post below?

Comment: @Anixx : That integral is purely real. To resolve the singularity not to its principal value $0$ but toward something complex pre-supposes that the complex already is defined. You thus again define a new $i$ on the basis of an already existing $i$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann maybe. That's why I am not entirely sure.

Comment: @Anixx : You are trying to invent a Münchhausen trick, lifting yourself by your own boot laces. $i$ is, as was said several times, the generator of an *algebraic extension* of $\Bbb R$. In itself it does not have a geometric interpretation. It is *perpendicular* to the order structure of the reals. Conjugation is an *isomorphism*, the mirror image has the same algebraic structure. Identifying $\Bbb C$ with $\Bbb R^2$ and selecting $(0,1)$ as representing $i$ and that it points upwards is a *choice*, equivalent to the choice of what the preferred or positive orientation in the plane is.

Comment: @LutzLehmann see my post below. In dual numbers, $\varepsilon$ is also perpendicular algebraically to reals, but can be seen as an infinitesimal.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It sounds like you have picked up on the fact that conjugation $$f: a+bi \mapsto a-bi$$ is a [ring isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_homomorphism) where $i$ and $-i$ correspond to each other.

- Addition preserving: $f((a+bi)+(c+di))=f((a+c)+(b+d)i)=(a+c)-(b+d)i=(a-bi)+(c-di)=f(a+bi)+f(c+di)$
- Multiplication preserving: $f((a+bi)(c+di))=f((ac-bd)+(ad+bc)i)=(ac-bd)-(ad+bc)i=(a-bi)(c-di)=f(a+bi)f(c+di)$
- $f(1)=1$

Conjugation is clearly bijective too.

Answer (score 5):

An idea: using the "identification" (in fact isomorphism, but making it a simple identification) of $\;\Bbb C\;$ with $\;\Bbb R^2\;$, we have that $\;z=x+iy \stackrel{\text{Ident.}}\sim (x,y)\;$, and thus

$$i\sim(0,1)\;,\;\;\text{whereas}\;\;-i\sim (0,-1)$$

and that's one way (a rather simple and algebraic one) to distinguish completely $\;i\;$ from $\;-i\;$ .

Comment: That's great, but if there is any function that ultimately behaves differently to i then it does to -i? Because then we would want to SURE to map the "right" i to (0, 1)

Comment: how do I know the i you use in x+iy isnt my x+(-i)y if we only say i²=-1. Is i actually a set of 2 numbers? There is always 2 complex planes? Can quaternions fix this?

Comment: I suspect that your identification is slightly circular: you are saying that $i$ is the complex number where the real part is $0$ and the imaginary part is $+1$. But you have to know which of the two solutions to $z^2=-1$ has the positive imaginary part to do the identification.

Comment: Since conjugation is an automorphism of $\mathbb{C}$, one cannot distinguish _algebraically_ between $i$ and $-i$.

Comment: @cmarangu A function that behaves differently in $\;i,\,-i\;$ ? Sure: the polynomial $\;z-i\in \Bbb C[z]\;$ vanishes at $\;i\;$ yet it equals $\;-2i\;$ at $\;-i\;$ . Your question in your second comments is just incomprehensible to me...and I don't think quaternions solve this at all. If anything, they make things messier as now there are three different elements $\;i, j, k\;$ that squared equal $\;-1\;$ ...!

Comment: @Henry No, I'm not saying anything like that at all. I'm just identifying $\;i\;$ with the point $\;(0,1)\;$ on the real plane. That **you** interpret this as it having real part zero and etc. is something that isn't included in this identification. Nothing circular here, as far as I can see..All the rest you write about the solutions to $\;z^2=-1\;$ is irrelevant about what I did and also about what the OP wrote in his question.

Comment: @DonAntonio your not circular, and tyou have a good point. However what is $z-i\in{}ℂ[z]$

Comment: @DanielFischer conjugation maps points on the real umber line to the real number line, points on the unit circle to the unit circle, and maps the complex plane to itself one-to-one. Also so does $f(z)=(-1)\cdot z$ which rotates the complex plane 180°. Are you sure there is absolutely no situation where $i$ behave differently then replacing all $i$ with $-i$? If so pls cite article for me to read

Comment: @cmarangu $\;z-i\;$ is a linear polynomial in $\;\Bbb C[z]=$\; the ring of polynomials with complex coefficients.

Comment: @cmarangu $z \mapsto -z$ is not a field automorphism, while $z \mapsto \overline{z}$ is one. I'm not sure there is absolutely no situation where one can distinguish the two square roots of $-1$ (of course once you've labelled them it's trivial to distinguish them by the label, but we're not looking for such a distinction), however the existence of a field automorphism exchanging the two means we cannot distinguish them algebraically [without leaving $\mathbb{C}$, it might be possible in some larger structure like $\pm\sqrt{2}$ can be distinguished in $\mathbb{R}$]

Answer (score 4):

As @DanielFischer commented, $\mathbb C$ has the complex-conjugation automorphism that interchanges the two square roots of $-1$ (however we decide to label them). Thus, any algebraic relation (with *real* coefficients) that holds for one holds for the other. In different words, $\mathbb R(i)$ is constructed algebraically as $\mathbb R[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle$, and the image of $x$ is a canonical square root of $-1$ in that model. (But/and, also, the image of $-x$ is another.) But/and I think this is not the type of distinction you want.

It gets worse in the Hamiltonian quaternions: there are infinitely-many square roots of $-1$, and they are all conjugate to each other in the quaternions.

Yes, if we choose to represent complex numbers as the real plane, we can label/name the square root of $-1$ that is in the upper half-plane "$i$". But, as in my first remark, flipping/interchanging upper and lower half-planes is an isomorphism of $\mathbb C$ to itself, and it is essentially impossible to distinguish... so this hasn't really accomplished anything.

For contrast, the case of $\sqrt{2}$ is somewhat different. It is the same, in the sense that the field $\mathbb Q[x]/\langle x^2-2\rangle$ is abstractly made by adjoining a square root of $2$ to $\mathbb Q$, because the image of $x$ in the quotient is a sort of canonical $\sqrt{2}$ in that model. *BUT* the distinction that matters in practice is that $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2})$ admits two different imbeddings into $\mathbb R$, and in one the abstract square root of $2$ goes to $1.414...$ while in the other it is the negative of that. The "standard/canonical" square root of $2$ we usually refer to is actually the real number $1.414...$, rather than an abstract one.

Comment: Adding to your comparison with $\mathbb Q(\sqrt2)$: The conjugation $\sqrt2\mapsto-\sqrt2$ is an automorphism of fields, but not an automorphism of ordered fields. $\mathbb Q(\sqrt2)$ has an ordering which is not preserved under conjugation. $\mathbb Q(\mathrm i)$ has no such ordering which lets us distinguish $\mathrm i$ from $-\mathrm i$.

Comment: you lost me there. What is ℚ[x]⟨x² − 2⟩

Comment: @cmarangu, $\mathbb Q[x]/\langle x^2-2\rangle$ is meant to denote the quotient of the ring \mathbb Q[x]$ of polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb Q$ by the ideal generated by $x^2-2$. This way of rigorously and abstractly creating field extensions was initiated by Kronecker in the mid 19th century, to avoid "begging the question" of whether numbers existed "out there" waiting to be "adjoined to" fields.

Comment: @paulgarrett I see. I have heard of this "Ring theory" but have not studiet it yet. thanks for help though

Answer (score 3):

You could construct the field of complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$ as the real vector space $\mathbb{R}^2$ with an operation
$$ (a_1,b_1)\cdot (a_2,b_2) = (a_1a_2 - b_1b_2, a_1b_2 + a_2b_1). $$
It can "easily" be seen that $(\mathbb{R}^2,\cdot)$ is a field and has the same properties as the $\mathbb{C}$ you know and love. Now you could define the imaginary unit as
$$ i := (0,1). $$
Then $i$ and $(1,0)$ form a basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and we can write each element
$$ (a,b) = a + bi $$
by abuse of notation (by identifying $a=(1,0)a$).

Comment: So basically, note i in ℂ to be homogeneous to the (0, 1) vector in ℝ? and linear combinations of 1 and i (with real scalars) to be linear combinations of (0, 1) and (1, 0)?

Comment: should note - I'm actually used to defining conformal ℝ²→ℝ² transforms in terms of the complex numbers - my question was whether {1, i} homogenius to {1, -i} something like that

Comment: Well yes, it can be helpful to consider $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ transformations as transformations $\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$, but $\mathbb C$ can be defined in the way I presented. I'm not quite sure what you mean by two elements being homogenius to each other?

Comment: Stefan Hante

ONE: it is homogenious if it is a homomorphism    TWO: it is a homomorphism iff it is a linear map    THREE: it is a linear map iff f(a⃗)+f(b⃗) = f(a⃗+b⃗) AND f(ka⃗) = kf(a⃗)

Comment: Of course there is a homomorphism $f\colon \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ such that $f(1)=1$ and $f(i)=-i$. It is called the conjugation.

Answer (score 3):

Interestingly, a similar problem exists in [dual numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_number). Algebraically one cannot distinguish between $\varepsilon$ and $-\varepsilon$. But it is possible to augment their definition analytically so to distinguish them.

In dual numbers there is a common equality: for differentiable at $x=a$ function $f(x)$, $f(a+b\varepsilon)=f(a)+b\varepsilon f'(a)$.

Now, one can define that if at point $x=a$ $f(x)$ has right and left derivatives $f'_r(a)$ and $f'_l(a)$, and they are not equal, then
$f(a+\varepsilon)=f(a)+\varepsilon f'_r(a)$ and $f(a-\varepsilon)=f(a)-\varepsilon f'_l(a)$. In other words, $\varepsilon$ is defined as a positive infinitesimal, and $-\varepsilon$ is defined as negative infinitesimal. This provides an optional analytic definition distinguishing $\varepsilon$ from $-\varepsilon$, but the algebraic structure can work just well without such additional analytic property (but with it one can evaluate more functions at more dual numbers).

Still, in dual numbers one cannot distinguish $\varepsilon$ from $a \varepsilon$ when $a>0$ even with this analytic addition.

Comment: How can right and left derivatives not be equal when the dual numbers are commutative?

Comment: @runway44 please explain what do you mean.

Comment: Oh, do you mean derivatives defined by left and right limits? I was thinking you were talking about multiplying by inverses on the left and right (as in defining derivatives of functions of quaternions, for example). If so, where do your formulas for $f(a+\varepsilon)$ and $f(a-\varepsilon)$ in terms of left/right derivatives come from? If they're basically definitions, I would not consider this a way of distinguishing $\pm\varepsilon$.

Comment: @runway44 yes, left and right limits. When they are equal, they are called just the derivative.

Comment: @Anixx If I say f(x) = 1/x then it gives different values for the left and right infinitessimals ε=0+ and ε=0-

does this not work because we only define the infinitessimals for functions where they are diffrentiable?

Comment: @cmarangu the function 1/x has infinite limits from left and right at x=0. We are talking about functions which have finite left and right derivatives.

Comment: @Anixx then how about f(x) = 2⋅arctan(1/x)  from the left side 0- the limit is -π but from the right side 0+ the limit is π

Comment: @cmarangu division by $\varepsilon$ is prohibited in dual numbers, so one cannot insert it into this function anyway. The formula requires $f(0)$ defined.

Comment: @Anixx what if I try to cheat and use 2⋅arctan(tan(π/2+x)) ? this function is also -π for 0- and π for 0+ but the division is hidden within tan(x)=sin(x)/cos(x) here is a plot of it on graphtoy: https://bit.ly/3G8zpL2

Comment: @cmarangu as you can see, the formula (any of the above) to be evaluated at $\varepsilon$ requires $f(0)$ defined. It is the real part of $f(\varepsilon)$. So, your function has to be continuous at $0$ to be defined at $\varepsilon$.

Comment: @cmarangu Right side derivative of a function is $f_r'(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h$, so $f(x)$ should be defined for the right-hand-side derivative to exist.