# Do positive and negative imaginary numbers work exactly the same?

Tags: complex-numbers, symmetry

Can you take any true statement involving complex numbers, replace every instance of $i$ with $-i$ and every instance of $-i$ with $i$, and get another true statement? Obviously you can't do this with the real numbers; the positive reals are closed under multiplication and the negative reals aren't. But if you can do it with $i$, how would you prove this very general proposition? Just in case it isn't clear what I mean, here's an example:

$$\text{"}(\alpha+\beta i)^2=\alpha^2+2\alpha\beta i -\beta^2\text{"} \longmapsto  \text{"}(\alpha-\beta i)^2=\alpha^2-2\alpha\beta i -\beta^2\text{"}$$
This is probably a naïve question, but I haven't really dealt with complex numbers at all.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $-1$ is the square of two imaginary numbers and there is no good way of distinguishing them apart from calling an arbitrary one $i$, making the other $-i$.  But it would work just as well calling the second $j=-i$ and so the first $-j=i$.  Your observation is that you can use either choice and get the same results for arithmetic on the complex numbers, though you used $i$ and $i$ rather than $i$ and $j$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Symbolic definition for $i$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3886413/symbolic-definition-for-i)

Comment: Relevant: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/423796/why-we-can-analytically-define-%ce%b5-in-dual-numbers-so-to-distinguish-%ce%b5-from

Comment: $\ln (-1)=i \pi$, not $-i \pi$ but this is just a convention.

Comment: Not a naive question at all, but an important one. As explained in the answer below, this is because conjugation is an automorphism. i.e., $\overline{ab} = \overline{a}\overline{b}$, $\overline{a+b} = \overline{a+b}$, and $\overline{ca} = c\overline{a}$ when $c \in \mathbb{R}$. From repeating these rules you can prove any of the kind of identity you wish, assuming the variables $\alpha, \beta$ etc. are real numbers.

Comment: To use your example,
\begin{align*}
(\alpha+\beta i)^2=\alpha^2+2\alpha\beta i -\beta^2
\implies \overline{(\alpha+\beta i)^2}=\overline{\alpha^2+2\alpha\beta i -\beta^2}\\
\implies \overline{(\alpha+\beta i)}^2=\overline{\alpha^2}+\overline{2\alpha\beta i} - \overline{\beta^2}\\
\implies(\alpha-\beta i)^2=\alpha^2-2\alpha\beta i -\beta^2.
\end{align*}

Comment: I think you are getting at the "should I call this electr charge pos or neg? I'll call it pos $\implies$ electrons are forever saddled with a negative charge" issue.  When we had a bunch of real numbers scattered on the floor and we put them in a line and said: I'll call the ones to the right *positive* and the ones to the left negative and I'll use the symbol $<$ to mean to the left, we could just as easily switched our definitions and nothing would have changed. If we had defined $-1$ as the mult id. *OR* if we had declared $a<b\implies ac<bc$ when $c<0$ math would still work the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that this actually works, and this operation, a.k.a. complex conjugation, is an "automorphism," which means it's a symmetry under some operations. It is an automorphism of complex numbers under addition, multiplication, limits, differentiation, integration, and more. This is true since $i$ and $-i$ are both square roots of $-1,$ and we can define the complex numbers using either of those as "the real" $i.$ However, arguments and imaginary parts are totally dependent on what is "the real" $i,$ since they are not algebraic.

Comment: Maybe you intended to write "complex conjugation" instead of "automorphism", right?

Comment: That information is worth including in the post, but so is the automorphism information.

Comment: Thank you! Someone linked a question similar to mine that I didn't find before posting, but I think your answer is more complete than the accepted answer to that question, at least for my motivation of the question.

Comment: Where is that question?

Answer (score 4):

> Can you take any true statement involving complex numbers, replace every instance of $i$ with $−i$ and every instance of $−i$ with $i$, and get another true statement?

Depends on what you mean by **any true statement**.  The following true statement represents a counter example to your assertion.

For all $~x \in \Bbb{R},~$ 
if $\theta$ represents the *argument* to $(x + i),$ 
then $\sin(\theta) > 0.$